# Django query datetime < '2014-12-22'

Tags: python, django

I have a time `tomorrow` : 2014-12-22 :

```
tt = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.utc).replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc) + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
tomorrow = tt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")  #2014-12-22
```

I can use this sql to get the result

```
SELECT * FROM showtime
WHERE the_id=82 AND time < '2014-12-22'
```

And I want to know if I want to use this in django query ,how can I do ??
or is there a method I can query `time objcet` so that I can make sure the time is utc time

```
obj = Showtime.objects.filter(source=1,movietme< tomorrow)
```

Please teach me thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [lt](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#lt) field lookup:

```
obj = Showtime.objects.filter(source=1,movietme__lt=tomorrow)
```